# Regex to split clipboard from excel

Tags: c++, regex, qt, split

I'm using QT to handle clipboard data from Excel.

For multiple line in cell, Excel wrap with double quotes.
Example clipboard data:
Pentium\n is a brand used for a series of x86 architecture "compatible microprocessors\n produced by Intel since 1993."

Expected result:

```
Pentium

is a brand used for a series of x86 architecture

compatible microprocessors
produced by Intel since 1993.
```

can anyone provide regex to split it and give result above?

Comment: Looking at a regular expression tutorial may be appropriate.

Answer (score -2):

Pattern: `\"([^"]+)\"`

```
\"    // a double quote char
(     // start of captured group (ends up as $1 or \1 depending on language)
[^"]+ // 1 or more characters not a double quote
)     // end of group
\"    // a double quote char
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/mfIrm1/1)

Java code:

```
String in = "a b c \"d e f\"";
String out = in.replaceAll("\"([^\"]+)\"", "$1");
assertEquals("a b c d e f", out); // Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Java is not part of the tags

Comment: OP asked for a regex pattern. I provided the code to show that the pattern works as intended. I don't know c++ but I know regex.

Comment: Would you like me to respond with c ++ code when you ask for java?

Comment: Thanks for answer anyway. But the regex above is not match with \n outside of double quote